How to return more than one array in Protobuf service rpc
I have the following schema in my .proto file:
service DownloadOctants {
    rpc GetOctants (OctantsQuery) returns (OctantsResponse) {
    }
}

message OctantsQuery {
    repeated int32 octants = 1;
}
message OctantsResponse {
    repeated Mesh meshes = 1;
}
message Mesh {
    repeated float vertices = 1;
    repeated int32 faces = 2;
}

Mesh consists of two arrays. Is that possible?
If no, how else should I design my scheme?
If yes, how do I access the values of the arrays vertices and faces?
I saw the sample program at https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/basics/ :
var call = client.listFeatures(rectangle);
  call.on('data', function(feature) {
      console.log('Found feature called "' + feature.name + '" at ' +
          feature.location.latitude/COORD_FACTOR + ', ' +
          feature.location.longitude/COORD_FACTOR);
  });

This assumes that listFeatures returns an array, but only one array. It seems to be more challenging to process two or more arrays.

Q1 "Mesh consists of two arrays"
Yes, it's possible as you show in your protobuf.
Q2: "How do I access the value of vertices and faces"
The sample program (Route Guide) ListFeatures method streams responses and so the implementation is different.
Your proto returns OctantsResponse which contains 2 (vertices,faces) arrays so you can:
...
octantsQuery = {
  octants = [1,2,4,5,6]
};

client.getOctants(octantsQuery, (err, octantsResponse) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // Iterate over the Meshes
  octantsResponse.meshes.forEach(m => {
    // Iterate over the vertices
    m.vertices.forEach(v => {
      console.log(`vertex: ${v}`);
    });
    // Iterate over the faces
    m.faces.forEach(f => {
      console.log(`face: ${f}`);
    });
  });
});

It's good practice to include syntax and package definitions in your protos:
syntax = "proto3"; // Or?

package some-namespace;

...

